# Implementations of Undirected Disjoint Paths

Tags: graph-algorithms, implementation

I'm looking into the Undirected Vertex Disjoint Paths problem:

> Given a list of tuples of vertices (s_i, t_i)
>
> Find simple, pairwise disjoint paths P_{s_0,t_0}, P_{s_1,t_1}, ... that connects the given vertices. If they exist.

I'm in particular interesting in implementing a solution to this this for grid meshes. A situation that comes up in many pen+paper puzzles. I know this will be NP hard in the list of tuples, but hopefully not in the size of the graph.

I know about the Robertson-Seymour theorem, and its complications. However I'm wondering if the required minors might be well known for say planar graphs or meshes?

I also found mentions that Schrijver has made a more approachable polynomial algorithm, but I haven't been able to find mentions of complexity in terms of implementation.

Can anyone point me in a good direction?
I'd be interested even in solutions for just two pairs.

Comment: See http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.2378 and http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.4207 for two recent "theory" papers on planar disjoint paths. They will have pointers to previous ones. I don't know any references to implementations and would be happy to see some pointers.

Comment: Did you ended up finding any good solutions?

Answer (score 2):

If you want an implementation, Sage has one. With a LP, as usual ;-)

http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/generic_graph.html#sage.graphs.generic_graph.GenericGraph.disjoint_routed_paths

Nathann

Comment: But it uses Mixed Interger Linear Programming, which is NP-hard... Is it any good?

Comment: Many times the LP-based methods give good solutions in a reasonable amount of time if the instances are "easy". You should try them out.